# Using Setters with Constructors in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I use the setter of a private instance variable from the default constructor in Dart?

Given the example class:

```
class A {
  String name;
  int _age;

  int get age => _age;

  set age(age) {
    _age = age ?? 0;
  }

  A(this.name, this._age);
}
```

How can I use this constructor to go through the `set age()` function? Is there away aside from using a `factory`? I'd like to do something like this

```
A(this.name, newAge): age = newAge;
```

But I get an error forcing me to only set instance variables from the constructor, which has me just duplicating the setter:

```
A(this.name, newAge): _age = newAge ?? 0;
```

Am I missing something or is this just not possible with dart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *initialization list* of a constructor can be used only to initialize members (or call base class constructors). (Additionally, when the initialization list is executed, `this` isn't valid yet, so you can't access any members.)

If you want to do other kinds of initialization work, you can do it in the constructor *body* instead, at which point the object is considered to be sufficiently constructed for `this` to be valid:

```dart
A(this.name, int newAge) {
  age = newAge;
}
```

Also see:

- [Difference between assigning the values in parameter list and initialiser list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63319094/), which explains why this becomes valid only for the later stages of object initialization.
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/64548861/ for various differences between the different ways to initialize members and for an example where the different ways matter.