# Is there a difference in how member variables are initialized in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, construction

In Dart, is there a difference in assigning values right away vs in constructor like in Java?

```
class Example {
    int x = 3;
}
```

vs

```
class Example {
    int x;
    Example() {
        x = 3;
    }
}
```

I ask because when I was using Flutter and tried to assign a Function that uses setState to a variable, it was not possible with the former method but possible with the latter.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In your trivial case, it doesn't matter.

In general, you can initialize instance variables in a few ways:

### Inline (field initializers)

```dart
class Example1 {
  T x = value;
}
```

Advantages:

- Direct, concise.
- Member will be initialized in *all* constructors.
- Can be used to initialize `final` or non-nullable members.
- Member is initialized before invoking base class constructors, which is important when the base class constructor calls member functions that are overridden by the derived class.

Disadvantages:

- Cannot depend on construction arguments.
- Usually cannot depend on `this` since the initialization occurs before `this` becomes valid (i.e., cannot depend on other instance members). ([An exception is if the member is initialized lazily by declaring it `late`](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#lazy-initialization).  This requires the null-safety feature to be enabled.)

### Initializer list

```dart
class Example2 {
  T x;

  Example2() : x = value;
}
```

Advantages:

- Can be used to initialize `final` or non-nullable members.
- Member is initialized before invoking base class constructors, which is important when the base class constructor calls member functions that are overridden by the derived class.
- Can utilize construction arguments.
- The initialized variable *always* refers to a member variable, never to a constructor parameter.

Disadvantages:

- If the class has multiple constructors, initialization would need to be duplicated, or constructors should redirect to a common constructor.
- Cannot depend on `this` since the initialization occurs before `this` becomes valid (i.e., cannot depend on other instance members).
- Can initialize only members of the enclosing class.  Because initializer lists are executed before invoking base class constructors, they cannot set base class members.

### Constructor body

```dart
class Example3 {
  T x;

  Example3() {
    x = value;
  } 
}
```

Advantages:

- Can utilize construction arguments.
- Can be used to perform more complicated initialization, such as cases where the member cannot be initialized via a single expression.
- Can use `this` (i.e., can use other instance members).
- Can be used to set base class members.

Disadvantages:

- Cannot be used to initialize non-`late` `final` nor non-nullable members.
- If the class has multiple constructors, initialization would need to be duplicated or initialization code would need to be refactored out (such as, but not limited to, redirecting to a common constructor).
- Member is initialized *after* invoking base class constructors.
- If the constructor has a parameter that shadows a member variable, it's easy to accidentally refer to the parameter instead of the member. (See https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/2552 for details.)

There probably are some points I'm forgetting, but I think that should cover the main ones.

Direct, inline initialization occurs first, then initialization lists, then constructor bodies.  Also see [Difference between assigning the values in parameter list and initialiser list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63319094/), which explains why `this` becomes valid only for the later stages of object initialization.

As an example where it matters where members are initialized:

```dart
class Base {
  Base() {
    doSomething();
  }

  void doSomething() {}
}

class DerivedEarly extends Base {
  int? x;

  DerivedEarly() : x = 42;

  @override
  void doSomething() => print(x);
}

class DerivedLate extends Base {
  int? x;

  DerivedLate() {
    x = 42;
  }

  @override
  void doSomething() => print(x);
}

void main() {
  DerivedEarly(); // Prints: 42
  DerivedLate(); // Prints: null
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this and for maintaining it up to date, very informative and organized.

Comment: As your list shows, initializing final members that depend on each other currently requires using the _late_ keyword, which is somewhat counterintuitive. There's an [issue on Github](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1394) where this is discussed.

Comment: "Constructor body... Cannot be used to initialize non-late final... members". This is the reason I refuse to use dart. You should be able to set a final instance variable exactly once from the constructor body.

Comment: @still_dreaming_1 Then declare it `late`.  The constructor body executes *after* other initialization is performed.  Also, C++ is not much different; initialization lists should almost always be preferred over work in the constructor body.

Comment: @jamesdlin No, you should make as many of your instance vars final as possible and definitely not late. Dart makes you fight with the compiler constantly if you want to have final instance vars that are not late. I did finally find a good workaround though. Make the default constructor private and have a public factory constructor that is named the same as the class. The factory constructor can build up the params in the body and then pass their resulting value into the private constructor before returning, where they simply become the final instance vars.

Comment: @jamesdlin One advantage with that approach is the constructor factory will not have access to the instance members, unlike the constructor where it strangely does, even though the object is still being constructed.

Comment: @jamesdlin All of this could be avoided though if they just change constructors to work properly, don't allow accessing members and require final instance vars to be set exactly once anywhere in the constructor. As is they allow what they should restrict and they restrict what they should allow.

Comment: @still_dreaming_1 As I explained in [the linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63319094/), it's done for compile-time safety.  If you do everything in the constructor body, then it's like Java you might invoke virtual methods on an incomplete object.  Or you could take C++'s approach where virtual dispatch within constructor bodies is completely disallowed.  IMO, Dart's approach is the best of both worlds, and if someone doesn't like it, they have the power to choose runtime checks over compile-time checks by using `late`.

Comment: @still_dreaming_1 Personally Dart is one of the most pleasant languages I've ever used.  I can't recall many instances where I've had to "fight with the compiler ... to have `final` instance vars that are not `late`." Using `final`, non-`late` variables is usually not a problem with initializer lists.  If you need to perform some complex computation first that isn't allowed within an initializer list, then by all means use `late`.  That's what it's for.  Also, be aware that using a factory constructor will prevent your class from being subclassed.

Comment: @jamesdlin You are just making my points for me. I said that you should not be allowed to access members from inside the constructor. For some reason Dart constructors allow that even though they should not. I agree on your point that Dart is one of the most pleasant languages I have ever used, which is why I was so frustrated when I discovered these shortcomings. Fortunately, as I pointed out, I eventually found this workaround. I still wish the language made such a workaround unnecessary, but at least it prevents them from ruining an otherwise incredible language.

Comment: @jamesdlin You were also wrong about initializer lists are being a good solution to this problem. It is not a good language design when the language pushes you towards trying to completely construct the object entirely from inside the initializer lists, which is the direction Dart ends up pushing you in if you are trying to make all the instance vars final. Fortunately factory constructors provide an acceptable alternative, when combined with private constructors and when the factory constructor is named after the class.

Comment: @jamesdlin Also, stop pushing `late`. It is not a good solution to anything. It just makes the code less safe and prevents the compiler from being able to provide as much safety. When a language can't provide a good alternative to `late` this is a flaw of the language.