# Dart Null safety, need to use `!` even with with optional constructor parameter set in constructor body

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

I'm having to use the `!` null-check override when accessing a field that has an optional constructor argument.  I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this that I've not realized.

This optional, nullable field gets assigned a value in the constructor body if no argument is supplied.

```
class AuthService {
  http.Client? httpClient;
  
  AuthService({this.httpClient}) {
    httpClient ??= http.Client();
  }
}
```

Later when using `httpClient` I need to provide `!` even though it will never be null...

```
http.Response response = await httpClient!.post(createUri,
          body: jsonEncode(requestBodyMap));
```

... otherwise the dart analyzer tells me:
`The method post cannot be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be null`.

When I use the `late` keyword, Lint checking is telling me the "assign-if-null" will never happen...

```
class AuthService {
  late http.Client httpClient;
  
  AuthService({this.httpClient}) {
    httpClient ??= http.Client(); // ← lint says this is useless & will never run
  }
}
```

... because `httpClient` can never be null.

Should I just ignore Lint?

Should I be doing something completely different?

Answer (score 0):

> ```dart
> class AuthService {
>   late http.Client httpClient;
>   
>   AuthService({this.httpClient}) {
>     httpClient ??= http.Client(); // ← lint says this is useless & will > never run
>   }
> }
> ```

That shouldn't be valid.  Since `httpClient` is non-nullable, `AuthService({this.httpClient})` means that the `AuthService` constructor takes an optional named parameter that can't be null, which is a contradiction since optional parameters must be nullable.

At any rate, you should prefer to use initializer lists over constructor bodies when possible:

```dart
class AuthService {
  http.Client httpClient;
  
  AuthService({http.Client? httpClient})
    : httpClient = httpClient ?? http.Client();
}
```

Doing so avoids the need to need to use `late` (since you can initialize the member earlier).

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64548861/ for more details about initializer lists vs. using constructor bodies.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to examples [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/41574#issuecomment-616132948) & [that](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/41574#issuecomment-766654812) by Google Dart engineers and jamesdlin who had an answer here earlier, this seems to work:

- use a never-null member / field instance variable: `Client httpClient`
- **don't** use the syntactic sugar shortcut of `AuthService({this.httpClient})` in constructor

  - in English this means: *assign `this.httpClient` to our member var `httpClient` OR `null` if not provided*
- use regular, maybe-null constructor arg `AuthService({Client? httpClient})`
- in initializer list, if maybe-null arg is not null, use it, else use default:

  - `: httpClient = httpClient ?? http.Client();`

So this:

#### Not so good

```
class AuthService {
  http.Client? httpClient;
  
  AuthService({this.httpClient}) {
    httpClient ??= http.Client();
  }
}
```

... becomes this:

#### Better

```
class AuthService {
  http.Client httpClient; // ← never null
  
  AuthService({http.Client? httpClient}) : httpClient = httpClient ?? http.Client(); 
  // ← no constructor body →
}
```

## Initializer List

Just to be ultra clear on the initializer list line:

```
// ↓↓ class field/member instance, never-null
: httpClient = httpClient ?? http.Client();
// constructor arg ↑↑ supplied, can be null
```

In English: *assign to our member the supplied client if not null, else instantiate a client & assign that*.

Now the class never needs null checking on `httpClient` member or overrides like `httpClient!.post()`.

---

I find initializer lists tricky because they can be hard to read and it's not obvious when they are executed (before constructor body, assigning values to member variables, without access to `this` as no instance exists yet).

Furthermore, constructor default args must always be constants. But initializer list assignments can be non-constant computed values.

So this is not allowed:

```
AuthService({this.httpClient = http.Client()})
```

... since `http.Client()` is not a constant. (If it were a *constant constructor*, it would be OK).

But this is fine:

```
AuthService({this.httpClient}) : httpClient = httpClient ?? http.Client();
```

It's also easy to visually confuse the member instance with supplied constructor arguments in initializer lists. Without syntax highlighting, it's hard to read.
[image: initializer list syntax highlighting in Android Studio]

`↑ purple = member         ↑ grey = constructor arg`

Check out [jamesdlin's breakdown of inline vs. initializer list vs. constructor body](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64548861/2301224) for a better understanding of all this stuff.

Comment: This is weird, just after posting this, jamesdlin's answer re-appeared on this page.  Anyways, leaving my long-winded reply here.