# I'm trying to reverse a list in dart, but I get an error. How to fix?

Tags: flutter, dart

This list is inside a provider:

```
List<DailyData> _storeDataByDate = [];
List<DailyData> _reversedstoreDataByDate = _storeDataByDate.reversed.toList();
```

But the bottom line is marked and shows the message:
The instance member '_storeDataByDate' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression.

Comment: I guess the two lines are from a `class` definition?

Comment: Also, I am maybe a little confused about what you are trying to achieve? You are aware that the second list will be a new list which does not have any attachment to the first? So when you add a new element to `_storeDataByDate` it will not be added automatically to `_reversedstoreDataByDate`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64548861/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do it as a function instead of a variable.

```
  List<DailyData> _reversedstoreDataByDate() => _storeDataByDate.reversed.toList();
```