# How to assign variables inside a map data structure of the value part in dart?

Tags: dart

Have a look at my code here it's in dart programing language I have a map object which I'm trying to assign inside another map `object('question')`. Coming from a Python background this usually works since I'm new to dart I need help.

```
Map ageData = {
    "Below 18": 'hello kid',
    "Above 18": 'hello Young adult',
    'Between 28-58': 'hello adult',
    "Greater Than 58": "hello senior citizen"
};

var question = [{"questionText":"Age Group", "opt":[ageData]}]; 
// I get error here stating "The instance member 'ageData' can't be 
// accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the 
// instance member with a different expression"
```

Comment: can you confirm the error is with this code-block? I copied this code-block to dart pad and didn't get an error, I printed the object and it worked fine

Comment: i tried that too. it works but my vs code extension is throwing this error

Comment: Is this the full code? is it possible that the error occurs in another place in the code? As we know this code works fine

Comment: I'm coding for flutter framework using the vscode and this is the only place where I'm getting the error

Comment: when the piece of  code is in void main(), then there is no error. but put it inside a class like so ```class NewAppState  {
  final final_data = [];
  var i = '';
  Map ageData = {
    "Below 18": 'hello kid',
    "Above 18": 'hello Young adult',
    'Between 28-58': 'hello adult',
    "Greater Than 58": "hello senior citizen"
  };
  Map genderData = {"Male": "Male", "Female": "Female"};
  Map educationData = {
    "School": "Student Student",
    "College": "College Student",
    "Other": "Other"
  };
 
  List question = [{"questionText":"Age Group","opt":ageData}];}```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64548861/.

Answer (score 1):

As this code is within a class, you will not be able to access instance members in the initializer

However you can access this property if it is set to `static` as static members are available on all instances of the class.

```
class NewAppState {
  NewAppState();
  final final_data = [];
  var i = '';

  static Map ageData = {
    'Below 18': 'hello kid',
    'Above 18': 'hello Young adult',
    'Between 28-58': 'hello adult',
    'Greater Than 58': 'hello senior citizen'
  };

  Map genderData = {'Male': 'Male', 'Female': 'Female'};

  Map educationData = {
    'School': 'Student Student',
    'College': 'College Student',
    'Other': 'Other'
  };

  List question = [
    {'questionText': 'Age Group', 'opt': ageData}
  ];
}
```

Comment: lol i came to the same conclusion too but did'nt see your answer till i refrehed the page thanks bruh

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution, Next time please do mention that you've only pasted a snippet of the full-code.

Answer (score -1):

I did some reading on the documentation it says that I would have to make it static so i tried this

```
class NewAppState  {
  final final_data = [];
  var i = '';
  static Map ageData = {
    "Below 18": 'hello kid',
    "Above 18": 'hello Young adult',
    'Between 28-58': 'hello adult',
    "Greater Than 58": "hello senior citizen"
  };
  Map genderData = {"Male": "Male", "Female": "Female"};
  Map educationData = {
    "School": "Student Student",
    "College": "College Student",
    "Other": "Other"
  };
 
  List question = [{"questionText":"Age Group","opt":ageData}];}
```

and now it works fine I just added that one word static and it got fixed :) anyone curious can read the docs here
[open this link for more info](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#implicit_this_reference_in_initializer)