# Flutter- Non-nullable instance field 'questionAnswer', 'questionText' must be initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm learning flutter by following an online course. I'm at the lesson of creating classes. So we have to create a class that has a string and a bool property. Below is this class:

```dart
class Question {
  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Question({required String q, required bool a}) {
    questionText = q;
    questionAnswer = a;
  }
}
```

And the error is  showing like this:

```
Non-nullable instance field 'questionText' must be initialized.

Non-nullable instance field 'questionAnswer' must be initialized.
```

Someone please help

Comment: Add calss init code

Comment: Your online course may create with Flutter 1. Flutter 2 have `Sound null safety` now, so if something can be `null`, you can add a `?`, such as `String? questionText;`.

Comment: [Use an initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64546212/).

Answer (score 0):

As per the new null-safety rules, you can't initialise a variable of any datatype without specifying its value or doing a null check. Try this:

```
class Question {
  String? questionText;
  bool? questionAnswer;

  Question({@required String q,@required bool a}) {
    questionText = q;
    questionAnswer = a;
  }
}
```