# Named parameters can't start with an underscore on null safe flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am not sure why this fails? How can this be fixed?

As per this
https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#private_optional_parameter
it's being told to make them without underscores. But that makes the variable public instead of being a private?

```
class ContactElement extends StatelessWidget {


  final IconData _icon;
  final String _heading;
  final String _describer;

  const ContactElement({
    Key? key,
    required this._icon,
    required this._heading,
    required this._describer,
  }) : super(key: key);
}
```

please help

Comment: `final IconData _icon; final String _heading; final String _describer; ContactElement({IconData icon, String heading, String describer}) : _icon = icon, _heading = heading, _describer = describer;`

Comment: @pskink This should be the answer.

Comment: so write a self answer then ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got this answer in comments from @pskink. Posting it here

```
final IconData _icon;
final String _heading;
final String _describer;

ContactElement({
  IconData icon,
  String heading,
  String describer,
}) : _icon = icon, _heading = heading, _describer = describer;
```

Comment: This needs to extend the super class `super()` of `StatelessWidget` ([Dart explanation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#extending-a-class), look at my answer

Answer (score 4):

Underscore means a private field for Dart ([more here](https://flutterigniter.com/deconstructing-dart-constructors/))

```
class ContactElement extends StatelessWidget {
  const ContactElement({
    Key? key,
    required IconData icon,
    required String heading,
    required String describer,
  }) : _icon = icon,
       _heading = heading,
       _describer = describer,
       super(key: key);
  
  // Private fields
  final IconData _icon;
  final String _heading;
  final String _describer;

  // If you want that other parts of the code could to these
  // fields, use getters and setters. Here is a getter example. 
  IconData get icon => _icon;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible since if you define a constructor for private variables you can not instantiate the class outside it's file since the variables are private, so the alternative is:

```
 class ContactElement extends StatelessWidget {
   late IconData _icon;
   late  String _heading;
   late String _describer;

  ContactElement( {required IconData icon, required String heading, describer}) {
    _icon = icon;
    _heading = heading;
    _describer = describer;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just tested it does not seems to work.

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla The answer updated just needed minor refactors, I checked it and it works.

Comment: You should prefer using [an initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64548861/) instead.

Comment: `late` variables don't initialize on constructors, I think

Comment: `late` variables don't initialize on constructors, I think.

You also need to extend the super class `super()` of `StatelessWidget` ([Dart explanation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#extending-a-class)), look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71412824/9192954)