# Right way of using optional named parameters in Dart class constructor

Tags: dart

Dart noob here. I have defined a class as follows:

```
class Balance{
  String ccy;
  late Money receivable;
  late Money payable;
  Balance(this.ccy, {Money? receivable, Money? payable}){
   this.receivable = receivable??Money.from(0, code:ccy);
   this.payable = payable??Money.from(0, code:ccy);
  };
}
```

The reasons I have defined it as above are:

1. I want the payables and receivables fields **never to be null** but, at the same time, I don't want to always have to pass a value for these fields whenever a Balance object is created.
2. I want the ccy argument to be required and use that argument to initialize payables and receivables fields to 0.

Is this the right way to define the Balance class? Is there a better way?

Comment: Use initializer lists instead of making the members `late`.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/64548861/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic way to write this code is:

```dart
class Balance{
  final String currency;
  final Money receivable;
  final Money payable;
  Balance(this.currency, {Money? receivable, Money? payable}) 
      : receivable = receivable ?? Money.from(0, code: currency),
        payable = payable ?? Money.from(0, code: currency);
}
```

(plus documentation!)

By initializing the fields in the initializer list (which exists for exactly that reason), you can make the fields final and non-nullable an still initialize them using computations that rely on arguments.

I'd never use `late` for a public field. In this case, you actually do initialize it immediately in the constructor, so there is no risk of clients of the class accidentally reading the field before it's initialized. They just don't know that, all they see is that the field is `late`.
Even if you make the field `final`, a `late final` field with no initializer will still have a setter visible in the public API.

If you actually *want* the fields to be mutable, then you can remove the `final`. Then being `late` isn't as bad, as long as you still ensure that the fields are initialized before anyone else sees the object. Then you still usually do what I did here instead and avoid the `late`.

The one case where you might need `late` is when you need to create a cyclic structure of final fields. Something like

```dart
class MainNode {
  final String name;
  late final SubNode _sub;
  MainNode(this.name, String data) {
    _sub = SubNode(this, data);
  }
  SubNode get sub => _sub; 
}
class SubNode {
  final MainNode parent;
  String data;
  SubNode(this.parent, this.data);
}
```

For something like this, where you need to create the sub-node *after* you have access to `this`, a `late final` field makes sense, and ensures that `_sub` is actually only written once. (I avoid exposing the `_sub` setter in the API by making it private, though.)