# Flutter Error: Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read

Tags: flutter, mobile

I've been trying to use attributes I created in a flutter class but it keeps on giving me this error
Error: Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read

```dart
class PatientDetails extends StatelessWidget {
    final Patient currPatient;
    PatientDetails({Key? key, required this.currPatient}) : super(key: key);
    final TextStyle titleStyle = TextStyle(
        fontSize: 15,
        color: Color(0xFF1F1F1F,),
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600

    );
    final TextStyle infoStyle = TextStyle(
        fontSize: 15,
        color: Color(0xFF222222,),
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600

    );
    List<Widget> info = [
      Opacity(
          opacity: 60,
          child: Text("Name",style: titleStyle,)
      ),
      Opacity(
          opacity: 90,
          child: Text(currPatient.getName(),style: infoStyle,)
      ),

    ];
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    InfoContainer(list: info, title: "Info")
                  ],
                )
            ),
          )
      );
    }
}
```

I tried to change the constructor and I tried using getter method but nothing worked

Comment: See [Is there a difference in how member variables are initialized in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64546212/) to understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lazy initialization with

```
late List<Widget> info = [...];
```

Also you can override initState.