# Constructor syntactic sugar for setting fields in Dart fails when fields are added via mixin

Tags: dart

Why doesn't constructor syntactic sugar for setting fields work when importing fields from a mixin?

```
mixin Nameable { 

  var name = '';

}

class Person with Nameable {

  Person(this.name);

}
```

Fails with error-message `'name' isn't a field in the enclosing class.`

This is ok though

```
mixin Nameable { 

  var name = '';

}

class Person with Nameable {

  Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

}
```

Report as a bug?

Comment: The two aren't actually equivalent.  The `Person(this.name);` syntactic sugar is equivalent to `Person(String name) : name = name;`, and initialization lists are processed *before* constructing base classes.  [The constructor body executes in a different phase of object construction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63319094/), *after* constructing base classes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializing formals, and initializer list entries, in generative constructors can only initialize fields which are *declared* in the same class.

A field introduced by a mixin, like here, is not declared in the class. It's mixed into a mixin application class, `Object with Namable`, which becomes the superclass of `Person`.

Assigning to the field in the body of a constructor is just normal assignment, not initialization. It wouldn't work if you wanted the field to be `final`.