# How do I initialize non-nullable members in a constructor body?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

I've created my class in Dart this way, but I'm getting the `Non-nullable instance field 'text' must be initialized. Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it 'late'.` I would like to know if there's a way to do it in a 'Python' style where this kind of class creation is possible, thank you in advance.

```dart
class Lexer {
  String _text;
  int _pos;
  String _current_char;

  Lexer(String text) {
    this._text = text;
    this._pos = -1;
    this._current_char = '';
    this.advance();
  }

  void advance() {
    this._pos++;
    this._current_char = this._pos < this._text.length ? this._text[this._pos] : '';
  }
}
```

Comment: I am changing the title of this question from "How to create a Python like class in Dart?" to be less vague and more easily searchable.

Comment: I found it right away with the "initialize non-nullable" title, which is the essence of your excellent question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```dart
class Lexer {
  String _text;
  int _pos;
  String _current_char;
```

This declares several members with type `String`.  Since they are declared as `String` and not as `String?`, these members are *non-nullable*; they are not allowed to ever be `null`. (This is part of the new null-safety feature from Dart 2.12.)

[Dart initializes objects in two phases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63319094/).  When the constructor's *body* runs, Dart expects all member variables to already be initialized.  Because your members are non-nullable and haven't been initialized to non-null values yet, this is an error.  The error message explains what you can do:

> Non-nullable instance field 'text' must be initialized. Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it 'late'.

- Use initializer expressions.  This means using an [*initializer list*](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list):

  ```dart
  Lexer(String text)
    : _text = text,
      _pos = -1,
      _current_char = '' {
    advance();
  }
  ```

  Note that if you're initializing members with a construction parameter of the same name, you can use shorthand:

  ```dart
  Lexer(this._text)
    : _pos = -1,
      _current_char = '' {
    advance();
  }
  ```
- Adding field initializers.  This means initializing members *inline* in the class declaration.

  ```dart
  class Lexer {
    String _text = '';
    int _pos = -1,
    String _current_char = '';
  ```
- [Marking your members as `late`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#late-variables).  This means that you promise that the variables will be initialized before anything attempts to use them.

  ```dart
  class Lexer {
    late String _text;
    late int _pos,
    late String _current_char;
  ```
- Making your members nullable, which allows them to be implicitly null by default:

  ```dart
  class Lexer {
    String? _text;
    int? _pos,
    String? _current_char;
  ```

  However, that will require that all accesses explicitly check that the members aren't null before using them.

You also might want to read: [Dart assigning to variable right away or in constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64546212/179715)

Comment: Thanks for incorporating changes in my answer and it's really kind of you that you marked this post duplicate given that this post was created a few days ago I created mine (I honestly didn't know this posted existed in the first place otherwise I wouldn't have created that post).