# how to avoid null option in classes

Tags: flutter, dart

In my class it calls _TextField it indicates an initialization error, but I initialize everything in a constructor, in the dart error documentation it mentions a solution, but I do not see the sense because I use constructors to initialize, I could give your opinion please

[image: Question image]

Comment: Can you add code snippet instead of image?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I initialize non-nullable members in a constructor body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66725613/how-do-i-initialize-non-nullable-members-in-a-constructor-body)

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify constructor

```
TextFieldDatos(
  this.iconoPrima,
  this.texto,
  this.ocultar,
  this.subTexto,
  this.iconoSecon);
```