# Dart Initializing Class Fields "Non-Nullable instance field must be initialized"

Tags: dart, class, constructor

I'm new to Dart, and I was learning about Classes in Dart.

I'm facing a problem understanding how constructors **in Dart** actually work.

I was used to initialize fields within constructors in the following way with other programming languages, but in Dart I get many warnings and errors with the following way of initializing fields.

```
class Car {
  String brand;
  String model;
  int year;
   
   Car(String brand, String model, int year) {
      this.brand = brand;
      this.model = model;
      this.year = year;
   }
}
```

I think that the problem is concerned with the null safety in Dart, but I don't want to use the `?` operator or the keyword `late` at the time of the fields declaration.

So, could anyone tell me how I could initialize the fields properly using constructors in Dart?

Thanks

Comment: [How do I initialize non-nullable members in a constructor body?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66725613/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the constructor body is essentially just a function. Which means you can do anything that a function can normally do. Including this:

```dart
class Car {
  String brand;
  String model;
  int year;
   
  void printCarDetails() => print("This car is from $year");

  Car(String brand, String model, int year) {
    printCarDetails();  // <-- what should this print?
    this.brand = brand;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;   // <-- if [year] is only initialized here?
  }
}
```

The problem is that you can use fields before you've initialized them (remember that `int` isn't `null` by default -- `int?` is). Dart needs a section *before* the constructor body where you can guarantee you've initialized everything, and then you can run your constructor body as normal.

That section is called an [initializer list](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list):

```dart
class Car {
  String brand;
  String model;
  int year;

  Car(String brand, String model, int year) : 
    brand = brand,
    model = model,
    year = year
  {
    printCarDetails();
  }
    
  void printCarDetails() => print("This car is from $year");
}
```

So everything after the `:` is just initializing fields, and then everything in the `{ }` is the constructor body, which can then access those fields.

But the initializer list is ugly to look at. Thankfully, Dart provides a shorthand called [initializing formal parameters](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializing-formal-parameters):

```dart
class Car {
  String brand;
  String model;
  int year;
  
  Car(this.brand, this.model, this.year) {
    // brand, model, and year are all initialized now
    printCarDetails();
  }

  void printCarDetails() => print("This car is from $year");
}
```

This is the idiomatic way of initializing fields, and you should try to stick to this pattern when you can.

---

As a side note, you may run into this problem when using the constructor of a *super* class:

```dart
class Vehicle {
  String brand;
  Vehicle(this.brand);
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
  String model;

  // Passes [model] to the initializer list, and [numWheels] to Vehicle
  Car(this.model, super.numWheels);
}
```

This feature is called [super parameters](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#super-parameters), and it is relatively new.

Answer (score 0):

Instance fields must either have an initializer at the declaration, use an initializing formal, or be initialized in the constructor's initialization list.
Here are the examples:

```
// initializer at the declaration
class Car {
  String brand = 'Brand';
  String model = 'Model';
  int year = 2023;

  Car();
}

// initializing formal
class Car {
  String brand;
  String model;
  int year;

  Car(this.brand, this.model, this.year);
}

// constructor's initialization list
class Car {
  String brand;
  String model;
  int year;

  Car(String brand, String model, int year)
      : this.brand = brand,
        this.model = model,
        this.year = year;
}
```

For more information and better understanding why dart works in that way please read the official [documentation](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#uninitialized-variables).