# Dart/Flutter - access private members of mixin or in derived class

Tags: class, dart, private, mixins, getter-setter

I want to outsource redundant class members into a separate class/mixin. For each class, which uses that class/mixin, I want to decide individually whether the members are gettable and/or settable from the outside.

I'd like to have something like the example below, but that doesn't compile, seemingly because private attributes are not visible when derived or added to a class via `with`.

So far, I haven't come to a reasonable solution yet. Any ideas?

```
mixin Person {
  String _firstName;
  String _lastName;
}

class Butcher with Person {
  Butcher({
    String firstName,
    String lastName,
  }) :
        _firstName = firstName,
        _lastName = lastName;

  final String tool = 'knife';
  
  String get firstName => _firstName;
  String get lastName => _lastName;
}

class SecretAgent with Person {
  SecretAgent({
    String firstName,
    String lastName,
  }) :
        _firstName = firstName,
        _lastName = lastName;

  final String tool = 'poison';
          
  String get firstName => _firstName;
  String get lastName => _lastName;
  
  set firstName(String value) => _firstName = value;
  set lastName(String value) => _lastName = value;
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with private members. Dart initializer lists can initialize only members of *that* class, not from any base classes (including mixins). ([Member initialization from initializer list executes *before* base class constructors.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63319094/))

It should work if you instead move initialization to the constructor body:

```dart
class Butcher with Person {
  Butcher({
    String firstName,
    String lastName,
  }) {
    _firstName = firstName;
    _lastName = lastName;
  }

  ...


class SecretAgent with Person {
  SecretAgent({
    String firstName,
    String lastName,
  }) {
    _firstName = firstName;
    _lastName = lastName;
  }

  ...
```