# Non-nullable instance field must be initialized

Tags: dart

```dart
class Foo {
  int count; // Error
  void bar() => count = 0;
}
```

Why I'm seeing an error when I am already initializing it in the `bar` method? I could understand this error if `count` was marked `final`.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

(*Your code was fine before Dart 2.12, null safety*)

With null safety, Dart doesn't know if you actually assigned a value to `count`.  [Dart initializes objects in two phases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63319094/), and Dart expects all member variables to already be initialized when the constructor's body executes. Because your members are non-nullable and haven't been initialized to non-null values yet, this is an error.

##### 1. At the time of declaration:

```dart
int count = 0;
```

##### 2. In the initializing formals parameters:

```dart
Foo(this.count);
```

##### 3. In the [initializer list](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list):

```dart
Foo() : count = 0;
```

##### 4. Use [the `late` keyword](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#late-variables):

This means that you promise that the variables will be initialized before anything attempts to use them.

```dart
class Foo {
  late int count; // No error
  void bar() => count = 0;
}
```

##### 5. Make the variable nullable:

```dart
class Foo {
  int? count; // No error
  void bar() => count = 0;
}
```

However, that will require that all accesses explicitly check that the members aren't null before using them.

---

Also see: [Dart assigning to variable right away or in constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64546212/179715)

Answer (score 9):

Use the late keyword to initialize a variable when it is first read, rather than when it's created.

```dart
class Questionz {
    late String questionText;
    late bool questionAnswer;

    Questionz({required String t, required bool a}) {
        questionText = t;
        questionAnswer = a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

IN my case i found  giving ? and ! to the variable helpful:

```
 double? _bmi; // adding ? to the double 

  String calculateBMI(){

    _bmi=weight/pow(height/100, 2);
     return  _bmi!.toStringAsFixed(1);// adding ! to the private variable


}

 String getResult(){
    if(_bmi!>=25){ //adding ! to the private variable
     return 'Overweight';
     } else if (_bmi!>=18.5)
   {
      return 'normal';
    }else{return 'underweight';}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

in pubspec.yaml if you are using :
`environment: sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"`

change to `environment: sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"`

2.12.0 null safety feature is on &
2.7.0 null safety feature is off

tip : instead of copy change manually

for more info https://dart.dev/null-safety

for null safety use `?` after variable like `var a?` and while using the variable  use `!` after variable  , like : `if(a!){}`

Comment: So, you're basically telling me to opt out of null safety? Sorry, this isn't something I was looking for !

Comment: your call bro ...I didn't want null safety in project amd got the same error

Comment: for nulll safety use ? after variable like var a? and  while using , use ! after variable ,like : if(a!)

Comment: First, how long can you stay there without null safety? Second, I've already provided that solution in my answer.

Comment: my  error was , due to await and then in ascyn function  , I was getting value from another class , which returns future , soo the error was you can't return a variable with ? because of await and then ....

Comment: It appears this answer was flagged as _Not an Answer_. It very much _is_ an answer. It is an answer with undesirable side effects—but that's why it's been downvoted, which is the correct action for answers that aren't useful. Answers that provide a sincere effort at answering the question should not be deleted (unless, of course, they are just a link).