# The non-nullable variable '_database' must be initialized

Tags: sql, database, flutter, dart, sqflite

I am using flutter to make a Windows app and while using the sqflite and making a database, this error pops up I don't know how to really fix this.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  static final _dbName = 'Database.db';
  static final _dbVersion = 1;
  static final _tableName = 'my table';

  static final columnId = '_id';
  static final columnName = 'name';

  DatabaseHelper._privateConstuctor();
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstuctor();

  static Database _database;
  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database == null) {
      _database = await _initiateDatabase();
    }
    return _database;
  }

  _initiateDatabase() async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(directory.path, _dbName);
    return await openDatabase(path, version: _dbVersion, onCreate: _onCreate);
  }

  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(''' 
          CREATE TABLE $_tableName ( 
          $columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
          $columnName TEXT NOT NULL)
          
          
          ''');
  }

  Future<int> insert(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.insert(_tableName, row);
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> queryAll() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.query(_tableName);
  }

  Future<int> update(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    int id = row[columnId];
    return await db
        .update(_tableName, row, where: '$columnId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  Future<int> delete(int id) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.delete(_tableName, where: '$columnId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }
}
```

This is the code i use for the databasehelper....it shows error in _database  like this:

```
The non-nullable variable '_database' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression.
```

Comment: Your variable `static Database _database;` is not assigned any value when initialized. So the value are going to be `null`. But because you are using Dart 2.12, the type `Database` is a non-nullable type so it can never be `null`. If you want to allow it to have the value `null`, you should change the type to `Database?` which allows the variable to point to a `Database` object or `null`.

Comment: thankyou it worked but now it is showing  "A value of type 'Database?' can't be returned from the function 'database' because it has a return type of 'Future<Database>'".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-nullable instance field must be initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67034475/non-nullable-instance-field-must-be-initialized)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There are two problems in your code which both comes from the new Dart non-nullable by default (NNBD) feature introduced with version 2.12.0. Both problems can be found in the following segment:

```
  static Database _database;
  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database == null) {
      _database = await _initiateDatabase();
    }
    return _database;
  }
```

First, in Dart 2.12.0, `Database` means a type which does not allow `null` as value. In your case, you define a variable `_database` which is not being initialized with any value. So this variable is going to have the value `null`. But `Database` does not allow that.

Instead, we need to use the type `Database?` which allows us to point to a `Database` object or `null`:

```
  static Database? _database;
  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database == null) {
      _database = await _initiateDatabase();
    }
    return _database;
  }
```

Now we get a new problem:

```
A value of type 'Database?' can't be returned from the function 'database' because it has a return type of 'Future<Database>'
```

The reason for this is Dart null-safety feature does not promote class fields when doing `if (_database == null)`. You can read more about that here and the reason why: [Dart null safety doesn't work with class fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65456958/dart-null-safety-doesnt-work-with-class-fields/65457221#65457221)

To fix this we can rewrite your code to:

```
  static Database? _database;
  Future<Database> get database async =>
      _database ??= await _initiateDatabase();
```

The `??=` operator will check if `_database` is `null` and set it to the value of `await _initiateDatabase()` if that is the case and then return the new value of `_database`. If `_database` already has a value, it will just be returned.

A good list of null-aware operators in Dart can be found here: https://medium.com/@thinkdigitalsoftware/null-aware-operators-in-dart-53ffb8ae80bb

You can read more about Dart non-nullable by default here:
https://dart.dev/null-safety

**Bonus**

I think you should also change:

```
_initiateDatabase() async {
```

To:

```
Future<Database> _initiateDatabase() async {
```

Since we do not not know which type `_initiateDatabase` returns and Dart will therefore assume it is `dynamic` which is properly not what you want.

Comment: Regarding your bonus point, adding Future<Database> before the method cause an error prompting to add a return clause. But adding "return _database;" will cause an error too: A value of type "Database?" can't be returned from the method '_initiateDatabase' because it has a return type of 'Future<Database>'.

Comment: @FMaz008 You need to read the code from the question. The _initiateDatabase() function is not suppose to return _database. Please also read about null-safety in Dart since you seem to get confused about that.

Answer (score 3):

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  static final dbname = "myDatabase.db";
  static final dbversion = 1;
  static final tablename = "myTable";
  static final columnId = "id";
  static final columnName = "name";

  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  static Database? _database;
  Future<Database?> get database async {
    if (_database != null) {
      return _database;
    }
    _database = await initiateDatabase();
    return _database;
  }

  initiateDatabase() async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(directory.path, dbname);
    return await openDatabase(path, version: dbversion, onCreate: onCreate);
  }

  Future onCreate(Database db, int dbversion) async {
    return await db.execute('''
         CREATE TABLE $tablename ($columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
         $columnName TEXT NOT NULL)
      ''');
  }

  Future<int> insert(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
    Database? db = await instance.database;
    return await db!.insert(tablename, row);
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> queryAll() async {
    Database? db = await instance.database;
    return await db!.query(tablename);
  }

  Future<int> update(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
    Database? db = await instance.database;
    int id = row[columnId];
    return await db!
        .update(tablename, row, where: '$columnId=?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  Future<int> delete(int id) async {
    Database? db = await instance.database;
    return await db!.delete(tablename, where: '$columnId=?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and explain what this code does, for more clarification. Read [answer] and take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help you,
please flutter sdk change as as follows

`sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"`  =>  `sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"`

Comment: this is not the right way to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best solution is to do the following, as it checks the _database variable is not null before it is used:

```
  static Database? _database;
  Future<Database?> get database async {
  if (_database != null) return _database;
  _database = await _databaseConnection.setDatabase();
  return _database;
  }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.