# The instance member 'text' can't be accessed in an initializer.Try replacing the reference

Tags: flutter

[Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAhkk.png)I am having a problem getting the value of a string into another string.
I am passing a text value from one screen to another and I can display the passed it into a final string and show it in a widget. I want to further use this value, but I cannot set this value to a string variable.

```
final String text;
ParcelDetail({Key key, @required this.text}) : super(key: key);
String ref = text; //error in this line
```

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67408949/why-does-this-error-occur-the-instance-member-cant-be-accessed-in-an-initi/67409176#67409176) to understand why this happens, and how to fix it.

Comment: Try initializing `ref` inside a methods like `build` or `initState`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the String "text" directly as a widget {"$widget.text"} into my function and resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `late` and `final` to `String ref = text`

```dart
late final String ref = text;
```

Every variable inside a `Stateless` has to be `final`

Comment: Here works fine [DartPad example](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id=1a28bdd9203250d3226cc25d512579ec)

Comment: > your example uses a widget to show the string and I am getting the same result when I use the widget but I cannot set title to a string variable