# dart instance member can't be accessed in an initializer from a factory

Tags: flutter, dart, lint

I'm trying to get my lint rules cleared and having a hard time finding a solution for 'implicit_this_reference_in_initializer'

```
class MyModel extends MyEntity {

 MyModel({ required this.myId, required this.myName } ) 
  : super(myId: tmyId, myName: tmyName);

 int tmyId;
 String tmyName;

 factory MyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MyModel(
   myId : (json['my_id'] as num).toInt(),
   myName : (json['my_name'] as String).toString() );
```

The above code produces the implicient this reference in initializer error.

If I switch to using the same variable names: myId and myName I get the lint rule: 'overrides-fields' : Don't override fields for: int myId; and String myName; variables.

At this point, I'm opting to just take the L(int..hah! get it? L ..lint...) for the error 'Don't override fields' as that seems the lesser of two evils.

Pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but there is no limit to define the same parameters.

```dart
void main() async {
  MyModel m = MyModel.fromJson({'my_id':0 , 'my_name': 'test'});
  print(m.myName);
  print(m.myId);
}

class MyEntity {
  final int myId;
  final String myName;
  MyEntity({@required this.myId, @required this.myName});
}

class MyModel extends MyEntity {
  final int myId;
  final String myName;
  MyModel({@required this.myId,@required this.myName}) : super(myId: myId, myName: myName);
  
  factory MyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return MyModel(myId: json['my_id'], myName: json['my_name']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Moving the declarations to the top still produces the lint rule errors. I am going to go with 'Don't override fields' and just over ride the lint error 

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of variable naming confusion,
so I'll just add a sample about how it should actually be.

Example:

```dart
class MyModel extends MyEntity {

 final int myId;
 final String myName;
  
 MyModel({this.myId, this.myName}) 
  : super(tmyId: myId, tmyName: myName);

 factory MyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MyModel(
   myId : (json['my_id'] as num).toInt(),
   myName : (json['my_name'] as String).toString() );
  
}

class MyEntity {
  final String tmyName;
  final int tmyId;
  
  const MyEntity({this.tmyName, this.tmyId});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your default constructor, not with your `factory` constructor:

> ```dart
> class MyModel extends MyEntity {
>
>  MyModel({ required this.myId, required this.myName } ) 
>   : super(myId: tmyId, myName: tmyName);
>
>  int tmyId;
>  String tmyName;
> ```

`required this.myId` and `required this.myName` are wrong; `MyModel` itself does not have members with those names.  The constructor then attempts to call the base class constructor using `tmyId` and `tmyName`, but the `tmyId` and `tmyName` members haven't been initialized yet, and [an initializer list can't read from member variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63319094/) anyway.

The correct fix is to get rid of `tmyId` and `tmyName`.  If the base class already provides corresponding members, then `tmyId` and `tmyName` serve no purpose:

```dart
 MyModel({required int myId, required String myName}) 
  : super(myId: myId, myName: myName);
```

If you somehow do need `tmyId` and `tmyName` members, then:

```dart
 MyModel({required int myId, required String myName}) 
  : tmyId = myId,
    tmyName = myName,
    super(myId: myId, myName: myName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the feedback. This is the final product: Shout out to @jamesdin for letting me know I had extra fluff in there and Mohammed Binmiskeen from [AdvancedJson2Dart](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16236-advancedjson2dart) IntelliJ plugin that helped me put the missing pieces together.

```
///json model implementation used by either local or remote storage
class BookOfTocModel extends BookOfTocEntity {
  ///constructor model forms data sources
  const BookOfTocModel({
    required int bookId,
    required String bookName,
    required String bookDescription,
    required String bookLanguage,
    required List<ChapterDataListEntity> chapterDataList,
  }) : super(
          bookDescription: bookDescription,
          bookId: bookId,
          bookName: bookName,
          bookLanguage: bookLanguage,
          chapterDataList: chapterDataList,
        );

  ///fromJson forms the model based off BookOfTocEntity
  factory BookOfTocModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => BookOfTocModel(
        bookId: json['book_id'] as int,
        bookName: json['book_name'] as String,
        bookDescription: json['book_description'] as String,
        bookLanguage: json['book_language'] as String,
        chapterDataList: (json['chapters'] as List<dynamic>)
            .map(
                (e) => ChapterDataListModel.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
            .toList(),
      );

  ///Reforms BookOfTocModel data to json format for placing in local cache
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(BookOfTocModel instance) => <String, dynamic>{
        'book_id': instance.bookId,
        'book_name': instance.bookName,
        'book_description': instance.bookDescription,
        'book_language': instance.bookLanguage,
        'chapter_list': instance.chapterDataList,
      };
}
```

If anyone sees any errors, let me know. But this produced no lint issues.