# How to distinguish the same variable name in dart constructor initializor list?

Tags: flutter, dart

As the Container widget has a constraints instance variable 。 But the constructor will also has a constraints parameter.

And in the initializor list,
We can see code like this:

```
constraints = (****） constraints;
```

So how do we know  which constraints is reference to the instance variable , and which one is reference to the function parameter?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name collision is not a problem in constructor *initializer lists*.  The left-hand-side of each initialization may *only* be a member variable.  From [the Dart language specification](https://dart.dev/guides/language/spec):

> ### Initializer Lists
>
> An initializer list begins with a colon, and consists of a comma-separated
> list of individual *initializers*.
>
> [...]
>
> An initializer of the form *v = e* is equivalent to an initializer of the form **this**.*v = e*, both forms are called *instance variable initializers*.

Meanwhile, [the expression on the right-hand-side cannot access `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63319094/) and therefore can *never* refer to a member variable.  Therefore:

```dart
class Foo {
  int x;

  Foo(int x) : x = x;
}
```

has no ambiguity: the member variable `x` is initialized from the `x` parameter.

The name collision can be a problem in a constructor *body*, however:

```dart
class Foo {
  int x;

  Foo(int x) : x = x {
    x *= 10; // This modifies the local `x` parameter.
  }
}
```

In such cases, the constructor body must be careful to explicitly use `this.x` if it needs to use the member variable, not the parameter of the same name.

Comment: thanks, I got it ! one more question  : where can I found  the place for rule "The left-hand-side of each initialization may only be a member variable" like the link you post for the right-handside?Or It's some thing conventional?