# Flutter: Unable to add local function in initialization

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, sprite

Forgive me if this is a simple fix but I am new to Flutter and I've had trouble finding a solution. I have one stateless widget, `MySpriteGame` which uses `SpriteWidget`. I have another widget called `SpriteSquare`, also stateless, which I am trying to add an event handler to. I'll add the code for both at the end (minus all of the imports to maximize space).

In want to pass down a function from `MySpriteGame` to `SpriteSquare` that basically adds `_whitesquare`, an instance of `SpriteSquare` to `_background`, another instance of `SpriteSquare`. The problem I am encountering is below.

`The instance member 'handleEvent' can't be accessed in an initializer.`

I know this is because I cannot add a function that adds `_whitesquare` to `_background` in the initialization of those variables. If `MySpriteGame` were stateful, I'd probably add the listener in an `initState` or something. I was wondering if there was a way to add these event listeners to the `SpriteSquare` nodes after initialization without having to make this widget stateful?

**sprite_square.dart**

```
class SpriteSquare extends NodeWithSize {
  
  Color color;
  Function handler;

  SpriteSquare(size, this.color, this.handler) : super(size){
    userInteractionEnabled = true;
  }

  @override handleEvent(SpriteBoxEvent event) {
    handler(event);
    return true;
  }

  @override
    Future<void> paint(Canvas canvas) async {
      applyTransformForPivot(canvas);
      canvas.drawRect(
        new Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height),
        Paint()..color = color
      );
    }
}
```

**sprite_game.dart**

```
class MySpriteGame extends StatelessWidget {

  final _background = SpriteSquare(const Size(400.0, 400.0), const Color(0xFF000000), (e)=>handleEvent(e));
  final _whitesquare = SpriteSquare(const Size(200.0, 200.0), const Color(0xFFFFFFFF), (e)=>handleEvent(e));

  MySpriteGame({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  handleEvent(SpriteBoxEvent event) {
    _background.addChild(_whitesquare);
    return true;
  }

  handleRemoveSelf(SpriteBoxEvent event){
    print(event);
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: 
          SpriteWidget(
            _background
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

I feel like I might be onto something by adding the function after the `Widget build...` and before the `return Center...`. I can do `_background.handleEvent()` but I'm not sure how to add the logic from the `handleEvent` above into this `handleEvent`.

Comment: [Non-`late` member variables are initialized before `this` is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63319094/).  In your case, the simplest fix probably would be to declare those members with `late final`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is best practice but I was able to initialize `_background` with `()=>{}` as the handler. Then after the `Widget build...` I have the line `_background.handler = handleAdd;` which enabled me to apply the logic in `handleAdd` to the `handleEvent` for this instance of `SpriteSquare`.

I am now able to add `_whitesquare` to the `_background`.

Comment: FYI, `() => {}` is a function that returns an empty `Set`.  If you want a function that does nothing, use `() {}`.

Comment: @jamesdlin that's good to know