# How to call method before initializing parent constructor in dart

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, oop

I want to call functions with my classes constructor arguments before passing them to the `super` method.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```dart
class CustomScaffold extends Scaffold {
  @override
  final Widget body;

  const CustomScaffold({required this.body, Key? key})
      : super(key: key, body: _buildBody());  // <--- it doesnt like this

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Center(child: body);
  }
}
```

This is the error that I am getting from AndroidStudio:

```
error: The instance member '_buildBody' can't be accessed in an initializer. (implicit_this_reference_in_initializer at [bordns_client] lib/ui/base.dart:11)
```

What is are the best practices for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call an *instance* method from an initializer list (nor before all base class constructors have been executed) because that would allow an instance method to be called before the object has been initialized; `this` is not valid yet. (Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63319094/)

In your case, you could make your method a `static` method or a freestanding function that takes `body` as an argument (or if you don't use `_buildBody` anywhere else, just pass `Center(child: body)` directly).