# Dart - Call Named Constructor using super vs class name

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class Person {
  late String name;
  late int age;
  Person();
  Person.ap(this.name, this.age);
}

class Employee extends Person {
  Employee(String name, int age) : super.ap(name, age); // This works

  // This is giving error. The method 'ap' isn't defined in a superclass of 'Employee'.
  Employee(String name, int age) {
    super.ap(name, age);
  }
}
```

What's the difference of calling unnamed constructor using super or inside the parenthesis?

Comment: `super` can be used only in a constructor's  initializer list.  This has nothing to do with named vs. unnamed constructors.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63319094/.

Answer (score 3):

try this, just create a setter function named `ap` in the `Person class`

```dart
     class Person {
          late String name;
          late int age;
          Person();
          Person.ap(this.name, this.age);
          
          ap(String name, int age){ //add this           
              this.name=name;
              this.age=age;
            }
        }
        
        class Employee extends Person {

          //here ap is name constructor 
          Employee(String name, int age) : super.ap(name, age);
          
          //here ap is setter function in the person class
          Employee.ap(String name, int age) {
            super.ap(name, age);
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are making two same-named constructors. Do something like this

```
class Employee extends Person {

Employee(String name, int age) : super.ap(name, age);

Employee.foo(String name, int age): super.ap(name, age);

}
```